# A conjecture on partitions

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, integer-partitions

While trying to prove a result in group theory I came up with the following conjecture on partitions:

Let $b(i,j)$  be the number of partitions of $i$  with greatest part exactly equal to $j$ , for all $i,j\in\mathbb{N}$. Suppose for $m\in\mathbb{N}$,  $a(m)$  denotes the number of partitions of $m$  with each part at least $2$ . Then the following holds: 
$$\sum_{i+j=m} b(i,j)=a(m).$$

I need to prove or disprove the above conjecture. I checked first few cases where it holds true. I tried induction and some bijection arguments but did not succeed. Any idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give a bijection argument: Interpret $b(i,j)$ as the number of partitions of $m=i+j$ with greatest part $j$ occuring at least twice. Then the LHS counts the number of partitions of $m$ with greatest part occuring at least twice.

Now give a bijection of the set of partitions of $m$ with greatest part occuring at least twice to the set of partitions of $m$ with each part at least $2$  by rotation of the corresponding [Ferrers diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29#Ferrers_diagram).